# ties in Wilcoxon t test in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank, ties

I have a paired data with a small sample size of 19 subjects who gave different scores at time 1 ($T_1$) and time 2 ($T_2$). I'd like to conduct a Wilcoxon test using R, because my data are not normal.
`wilcox.test` gives a warning message that says that exact p-value cannot be computed with ties and zeroes.

I have only 4 differences ($T_1-T_2$) out of 19 that are equal to 0. Can I still use this test?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this answer is to illustrate some possible tests for your data.  Suppose data are as follows:

```
x1 = c(5, 6, 3, 3, 4,  2, 5, 3, 4, 3,  4, 5, 3, 2, 2,  5, 4, 1, 3)
x2 = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 2,  1, 4, 5, 4, 2,  2, 4, 2, 1, 3,  5, 3, 1, 2)
```

**Wilcoxon signed rank test.** A paired Wilcoxon test is a one-sample Wilcoxon signed rank on differences.
Differences for the data above are:

```
d = x1-x2; d
[1]  1  1  0  1  2  1  1 -2  0  1  2  1  1  1 -1  0  1  0  1

hdr = "Stripchart of Differences"
stripchart(d, meth="stack", pch=20, ylim=c(.5, 2), main=hdr)
```

[image]

So there are four `0`s and many ties.

```
wilcox.test(d)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 99.5, p-value = 0.01842
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(d) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(d) : cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

The questionable P-value about 0.02 is below 5%. Just to get
an idea how seriously wrong the P-value might be (*not* as a formal test), you could use slight jittering to avoid ties and zeros.

```
j = runif(19, -.01, .01)
dj = d+j; wilcox.test(dj)$p.val
[1] 0.004577637
j = runif(19, -.01, .01)
dj = d+j; wilcox.test(dj)$p.val
[1] 0.04455948
j = runif(19, -.01, .01)
dj = d+j; wilcox.test(dj)$p.val
[1] 0.02582169
```

For my taste, this is enough of a clue that there may be a significant difference
below the 5% level. It seems worthwhile to look at alternative tests.

**Sign test for median of differences.** One alternative test for the null hypothesis that the mean is $0$ is a sign test. The `0`s contribute no useful information; out of the 15 non-zero
differences, 13 are positive and 2 are negative. So the P-value of a one-sided sign test is judged inconsistent with $0$ median, with P-value about 0.004.

```
pbinom(2, 15, .5)
[1] 0.003692627
```

Sign tests ignore how much positive or negative the differences are, so
their power is often not very good.

**Permutation test for mean differences.** Another alternative would be to do a permutation test, using the mean difference as metric. We randomly permute the signs of the 19 observations many times, find the mean each time, and compare the observed mean difference with
the simulated permutation distribution of means. [The mean difference is
an appropriate metric if we believe the original data are numerical (rather than labels of ordinal categories).]

The P-value (about 0.012) of a one-sided test is significant.

```
set.seed(319)
a.prm = replicate(10^4,  mean(sample(c(-1,1), 19, rep=T)*d))
mean(a.prm >= a.obs)
[1] 0.0118                        # P-val for one-sided test
mean(abs(a.prm) > abs(a.obs))
[[1] 0.0231                       # P-val for two-sided test
length(unique(a.prm))
[1] 17
```

There are 17 uniquely different permuted mean differences, as shown
in the histogram below, along with the observed mean difference (vertical red line).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Wilcoxon is performing a ranking and when there is a tie, there is not a method to properly assign one over the other.

For example, assume your data is x=(1, 2) and y=(2, 3) when you rank these values it could be (x1, x2, y2, y3) or (x1, y2, x2, y3).  Both rankings are equally valid but the the calculated statistic is different.  Because of this arbitrary ranking the warning is provided. If you dataset is large enough, with a few ties, it should all balance out.

For your case with your case, it might be more borderline depending on the p-value.  You could try rerunning the test a few times switching the ordering of T1 & T2 to see if the p-value changes.   Also, try running the test with the ties removed.

Good Luck.

Comment: Calculating tied *ranks* is one thing. Calculating an approximate *z* statistic that accounts for ties by correcting the standard error is another thing. And calculating *exact* test statistic and *p* values under a distribution of signed ranks is still yet another thing.